# The pbpaste command deletes newlines in the clipboard contents before writing to the target file

Tags: macos, bash, shell, applescript, command-line-interface

I'm writing the contents of the clipboard to a txt using [pbpaste](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html), for some reason it deletes all newlines from the text in the clipboard.

This is the command I'm using:

```
echo `pbpaste` > /Users/me/file.txt
```

It works as expected except for the fact that none of the newlines from the clipboard contents are to be found in the target file.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anyway to keep the newlines?

Yes, by eliminating `echo`:

```
pbpaste > /Users/me/file.txt
```

Comment: NVM, works now, must have done something wrong, without the echo command I can't write to the file, I get this error message: "-bash: Stack: command not found"

Comment: @TorThommesen The error is most likely (for sure) occurring elsewhere.